# Samsung Note layout issues

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile

In my application I have designed layouts for resolution 600x1024 and placed them in the `layout-large` folder.

When I run the app on Samsung Galaxy Tab it picks up layouts from the `layout-large` folder and the UI looks fine.

But for Samsung Note too it picks up layouts from the `layout-large` folder and the UI does not look good.

**Is there any way I can create an exceptional case for Samsung Note, and tell android not to use layouts from layout-large folder if the device is Samsung Note and instead use layouts from some other folder for this particular device???**

I have also designed layouts for resolution 800x1280 and placed them in the `layout-xlarge` folder. But even though Samsung Note has resolution 800x1280 it does not use layouts from this folder!!

I came across new size qualifiers here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts  but could not use this approach as my application's minimum sdk version is 2.3 (API level 9)

I have to support Samsung Note for my application and need a solution for this on priority, please help...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//check your density of your phone and create an layout and place your xml file there.

for medium density which is 160dpi

```
res/layout-large-mdpi
```

for high density which is 240dpi

```
res/layout-large-hdpi
```

for xhigh density which is 320dpi

```
res/layout-large-xhdpi
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. you can create a special folder for samsung galaxy note as following:

> res/drawable-sw800dp

which means smallest width is 800 dp. So gaalxy note falls in this category, but your 1024*600 tablet does not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tim. The layout-sw800dp folders are supported for Android SDK version3.2 and above. I'm using minimum SDK version 2.3, hence I could not make use of this solution.

Comment: @Zeba you can use a compatability package.