# Which layout should be used for samsung galaxy note 2 android

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, galaxy

I have to create an app which should be compatible with all the android devices i have searched alot for the correct layout but all were incompatible with samsung note 2

first the complete android documentation for multiple screen sizes http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support then some stack overflow questions [Samsung Note layout issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751343/samsung-note-layout-issues)
[What layout is suitable for 720x1280 Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008199/what-layout-is-suitable-for-720x1280-android-devices)

note 2 is not taking layout from layout-large folder
[image: this is my code for multiple screen layouts]

please suggest layout for samsung galaxy note 2

Comment: You don't need to create a diiferet layout for galaxy note, try to create a layout that fits good on all screen resolutions by placing view relative other view and using weights, you can also check my post for handling multiple screens here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16518557/1939564

Comment: For mobile screen resolutions you don't have to create different layouts, you need to create separate layouts on for tablets

Comment: there are layouts for different screen resolutions you should check the documentation [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

Comment: I know it, but its not necessary you use them all the time, they are supposed to be used for very rare cases, if you design your layouts wisely it will look good on all screen resolutions!

Comment: @babar i also design my layouts in 3.2 inch QVGA device all of them look great as you said but it is not looking nice only in samsung galaxy note 2 and samsung mega 6.3 inch

Comment: yeah you might need to create `layout-large` for 6.3 inch device and your galaxy note 2 will automatically pick its layout from `layout-large`, still if you want to set *widths* and *height* in percentage take a look at link i have posted above

Answer (score 0):

I support multiple layouts in my app, and Note 2 picks layouts from the layout folder, just like S3 or S4 does. The layout-large and layout-xlarge would be picked only if there is no layout folder in your project

Comment: so do i have to remove layout folder but removing this will make the app incompatible for normal screen devices

Comment: No, dont remove it. What i meant was that note 2 would automatically pick your layout folder and not layout-large or xlarge. So, make sure that you use sp, dip and weights. You dont need to remove anything

Comment: yes by default it is picking the layout folder but UI is not looking good how can i solve this

Comment: Make sure to use dip and sp instead of px. Also, make use of weights in linear layouts so that they auto-adjust according to screen size. Also, DO NOT use absolute values/layouts, instead use relatives everywhere

Comment: the layout folder shows the UI for normal screen which is looking awesome for normal screen devices but for note 2 and some large devices like samsung mega it is not looking properly

Comment: Try S4 and you would know that it does not look good in all the "normal" phones either

Comment: they use the same sw360dp = galaxy note2, S3 and galaxy nexus